# Visual Studio 2012 - "Error Access is denied" message box - no other information

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I occasionally get an error when I am using Visual Studio 2012. The error (below) gives me almost no information about what has gone wrong. It seems that the error is related to source control in some way as I usually get the error when alter a file (and the file gets auto-checked out) or add something new.

Other than the error message, nothing appears to be going wrong - source control checks out files for me and I can write to the checked out file.

I have checked in the output window and there is nothing obvious to show what is going wrong. Is there anything I can do to get a better idea of what is going wrong? Or has anyone else had the same problem and knows how to fix it?

[image: error message]

VS about box info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Premium

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012

Office Developer Tools   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual F# 2012   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Visual F# 2012

Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools   04941-004-0043007-02952
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools

AlignAssignments   1.0
Command for aligning assignments.

All Caps Menu Option   1.1
Allows you to turn all caps in menu titles on and off in the Visual Studio options dialog.

ASP.NET and Web Tools   2012.3.41009
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

AutoBraceComplete   1.0
auto brace complete

CustomDocWell   1.0
Provides configurable behavior for the document well in Visual Studio 2012.

JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3   C# Edition build 7.1.3000.2254 on 2013-04-10T16:48:18
JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains, Inc.

NuGet Package Manager   2.7.41101.299
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

OptionsPageImpl   1.0
Information about my package

PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010   1.0
A set of power commands for Visual Studio 2010

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

Quick Launch Tasks   1.0
Microsoft Quick LaunchTasks package adds accessibility and settings tasks to the Quick Launch tool.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: I have this problem as well.

Comment: Sorry @Eric I didn't manage to find an cause/work-around. Our team has moved to a cloud based TFS and the problem that I saw disappeared at the same time - I assume that it was related.

Answer (score 4):

The solution that seems to have worked for me is to update the security settings on this folder:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces

I made sure my user had full control over all files and made myself the owner for good measure.