# VS 2012 Csc.exe could not be run Access is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Imported a solution from VS 2008 to 2012, and got this error.  Tried everything in links below, and nothing worked:

[Visual Studio 2012 csc.exe Error. Executable not valid for OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297704/visual-studio-2012-csc-exe-error-executable-not-valid-for-os)

and:

[Visual Studio 2012 - "Error Access is denied" message box - no other information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701388/visual-studio-2012-error-access-is-denied-message-box-no-other-information)

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?  I uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2012 and all of the components, including Update 5, I ran the repair from Control Panel Programs, repaired the .NET framework, tried copying csc.exe from another W7 PC and several other fixes and nothing.  Solution still works fine in VS 2008...

Comment: Does the error happen only with that project/solution?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add.  Yes, only that project...

Comment: try with some other use account or from your office network

Comment: It's not clear what your exact error message is, but it sounds like you copied a solution with files (especially output files) that might be marked read-only or some other file rights making it inaccessible (e.g. wrong owner). Unfortunately, there's not really anything anyone on Stack Overflow can do to diagnose the issue. You'll need to track down the permissions issue yourself.

Comment: If you don't get the same error from a brand-new project of the same type, there's likely nothing wrong with Visual Studio. You might have to do a diff with a new project's project file (.csproj, etc) to see what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think I'll just try importing the elements of the project over from VS 2008 one by one to see if I can rebuild it that way.  It's a forms project, and there isn't any coding involved, just a good many notes.  I'll update with the results.  I did experiment with permissions on a folder I read about in Program Data\Microsoft.  Didn't work for me.  No idea why this happened out of the blue, but there doesn't seem to be any problem with any other projects I have.

Comment: Tried a new project, and that didn't work.  Importing elements didn't work.  Other existing projects are working fine though.  I didn't change anything system-wise, so I have no idea how to deal with this one.  Thanks for the help.  I'll just try working in VS 2008 for now.  Project is important to me, but it's not critical, and I might be able to finish it in 2008.  Appreciate the assistance...